# React Native App stuck in splash on xcode11.4.1 [IOS]

Tags: react-native

React-Native Version: 0.57.1

My App is working fine on xcode10.1, but when i'm running my App on xcode11.4.1 it stuck into splash screen.

Comment: Show me your AppDelegate.m file

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar

AppDelegate.m file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/129Q6Poq_sFg6LZltaFBiLjRDQzPMNkAf/view?usp=sharing

Error Image 1:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43812016/80911130-b6a05c80-8d34-11ea-83dc-e1e249603947.png

Error Image 2:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43812016/80911171-fa936180-8d34-11ea-8ce4-1502ac855c4f.png

Comment: @ahmad ashry I see your file on drive comment this line before return `[RNSplashScreen show]; ` and then reinstall the app and I hope it will works.